# Not able to login via SSH to GCP Compute Engine VM instance

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, centos7

My GCP VM instance was setup sometime back and all the services were working fine. However, suddenly from today I am not able to login via SSH and even an instance restart did not fix the issue. When checked the serial log, it seems to have stopped in this line,

> ```
>      [    8.686861] intel_powerclamp: No package C-state
>      availableintel_powerclamp: No package C-state available[    8.705723]
>      attempt to access beyond end of device [    8.706721] sda1: rw=0,
>      want=41927608, limit=41927602 [[32m  OK  [0m] Started Security
>      Auditing Service.
>
>      Starting Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown...
>      32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown.
>      Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
>      32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel
>      ChanWelcome to emergency mode! AfterGive root password for maintenance
>      (or type Control-D to continue):
> ```

It won't proceed further to start SSH and other services, hence I am not able to login to the instance. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> No package C-state available

points to problems to mount the filesystem.

Did you try to follow the steps written in this [other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685946/how-to-exit-emergency-mode-and-boot-to-default-mode) ?

When you see <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> enter root password. Then enter `mount -a` to see in what line is the error.

Enter `vi /etc/fstab` and correct whatever is missing, save and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is logon to the [serial console](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) so you can interact with it. It will probably ask you for a root password and if you have not set that up, you can set that up through [startup scripts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/startupscript).